# How to prevent loading state in Redux toolkit if the data has already been fetched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to stop showing the loading state if the data has been fetched, for example, if a user visits profile page, and move to another page, say Dashboard home if the user returns to the profile page, I don't want to show the loading state again.

This is how I'm fetching the data

```
 const { status, data } = useSelector((state) => state.profile);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProfile());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

and if `status === loading`, I show the loader, and if `fulfilled`, I show the `data`

The Reducer

```
 builder.addCase(fetchProfile.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.profile.status = 'fulfilled';
      state.profile.data = payload.data;
    });

    builder.addCase(fetchProfile.pending, (state) => {
      state.profile.status = 'loading';
    });

    builder.addCase(fetchProfile.rejected, (state) => {
      state.profile.status = 'error';
    });
```

Comment: Add the reducer code

Comment: @sojin done, please check it again

Comment: will update in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement it by either checking the data before calling the API or checking whether data is already there in API pending state

Method 1
**Checking the data before calling the API**

Call API only one time (in this method API won't call again and data won't be refreshed)

```
  const { status, data } = useSelector((state) => state.profile);

  useEffect(() => {
   if(!data) { //You can additionally check `data.userId` if needed
     dispatch(fetchProfile());
   } 
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Method 2
**checking whether data is already there in API pending state**

in this method, data will be updated in the background without showing loading

Check whether data is already there or not in the pending state.

```
  builder.addCase(fetchProfile.pending, (state) => {
      state.profile.status =  state.profile.data ? 'loading' : 'Data is already loaded';
    });
```